# Filter Firebase list using Angular2 Observable value

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, reactive-programming, angularfire2

I have a relatively simple problem that turned out to harder to solve than I thought it would. I'm basically looking to filter a Firebase list in Angular 2 using an observable value

Here's my initial code which works as expected and populates the locations variable with all the locations from the

```
  locations: Card[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cardService.getLocations()
      .map(locations => {
        return locations.map(location => {
          this.af.database.object(`/likes/${user}/${location}`).subscribe(like => {
            location.like = like.like;   
          });
          return location;
        })
      })
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.locations = result;
      });

  }
```

This works fine. Now, I want to filter the locations array based on the location.like variable.

If I run

```
this.locations.map(result => {
console.log(result) }
```

I get the full object as expected including the like parameter set to either true or false.

However, if I run

```
this.locations.map(result => {
console.log(result.like) }
```

I get back undefined despite this value showing up correctly when I console.log the full result.

Any clues on what could be causing this?